# SQL Query to summarize data for each column in table

Tags: sql, pivot, summary

I have a table like this

```
col_1 col_2 ... col_n
1      2    ...   3
2     -2    ...   
       0    ...   1
```

How can I generate the following table using sql?

```
col_name min max count
col_1     1    2     2
col_2    -2    2     3
       ...
col_n     1    3     2
```

I'm basically thinking I need to pivot somewhere but I can't figure out how

Thanks!

Comment: what SQL RDBMS are you using? SQL Server , MySql , Oracle ????

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to be as generic as possible..! but I'm using Oracle right now

Comment: i think that would be an unpivot

Comment: .. or store the values in a table(id, value) creating several rows instead of adding columns, then the query is a piece of cake.

Comment: @maraca I see your point... but how would you proceed for that? I'm having issues to understand how to have the columns as rows

Comment: @Stephane I see, you would group the table by id and just add the aggregation functions as shown in the other answers. For special cases (not here) you might have to use case when (works "everywhere") or decode (oracle).

Comment: @maraca can you please give a code snippet? I'm stuck :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `unpivot` should work, although you have to specify all columns in advance. If that's not practical you might want to look into dynamic SQL solutions.

```
select
  col        as col_name,
  min(val)   as min, 
  max(val)   as max, 
  count(val) as count
from (
  select col, val 
  from t -- your table here
  unpivot (
    val for col in (col_1, col_2, col_n) -- your columns here
  ) u 
) r
group by col;
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ccba/4) (Oracle 11g R2)

Comment: Thanks! dynamic would be awesome as well, at least for learning purposes :)

Comment: @Stephane I'm afraid I can't help you there as I don't know much about dynamic SQL in Oracle/PLSQL. For MSSQL there are several good answers here on SO, maybe there is some for Oracle too (I just don't know).

Answer (score 2):

```
select colname, min(val), max(val), count(*)
from (
select 'col_1' as colname,
col_1 as val
from t
union 
select 'col_2',
col_2
from t
-- and so on
) x
where val is not null
group by colname
```

This is one more way to do it. Thanks to JPW for his suggestions.

Comment: Your query will not quite work, although the basic idea is right; maybe this is what you intended: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0ccba/11

Comment: believe me or not..i was just about to post that.

Comment: Good, because that is what it should be :)

Comment: you can use it for sure.